# Magento 1.9 - JS block content of above-the-fold

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

My site with Magento in PageSpeed of Google is not fast. My problem is with code of JS and CSS because block content above the fold. I try to:

```
- add async parameter to js/css files in xml
- add defer parameter to js/css files in xml
- insert "ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"" in .htaccess
- insert "ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month""
- Merge JS and CSS files
```

All this without results. At this point, what could I do now?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I saw man, thanks. But i don't found the solution unfortunately.

Comment: cause there are none

Comment: what do you mean, "without results"? Did your changes actually change nothing or is Google just still complaining? Please provide more details, otherwise it's the same question as the linked duplicate and hard to give different answers.

Comment: Sorry, i meant that the speed of my site has remained the same on Google Page Speed (that is 70/100)​​. For this I did not know which method to use.